# subscribe_form.phtml not working in live, while working in local

Tags: magento2

I have a issue i have added this code in footer in my local magento instalation and its working.

```
      {{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="subscribe_form.phtml"}}
```

when i added same code in live site, the same magento installation is not showing it. what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running the production mode in your live site and the developer mode in your local site.

In the **production** mode, errors are **not** displayed, but instead logged in `var/log/debug.log` and `var/log/system.log` files. To identify the error, you can check one of these log files.

In the **developer** mode, errors are displayed and also logged in  `var/log/debug.log` and `var/log/exception.log` files.

If your `subscribe_form.phtml` template file does not exist in `Magento_Newsletter` directory in your custom theme, you will receive an error like this:

```
Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'subscribe_form.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Newsletter' block's name: 'subscribe_0'
```

Additionally, you should add the module namespace when declaring the template file, your code should look like this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe_form.phtml"}}
```